# What is the semantic meaning of "-07:00" in a DTS

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to find the semantic meaning of "2020-09-12T23:59:00-07:00" (coming from a third party web service) that applies to Las Vegas, NV.

I understand that Las Vegas (Pacific Time) is 8 hours behind UTC/GMT during winter and 7 hours behind during summer.

Is it -07 because 12th Sept is in summer? If so is "2020-12-12T23:59:00-***08***:00" the correct representation since 12th Dec. is in winter?

OR

If "2020-12-12T23:59:00-***07***:00" is the correct representation, how do we reason it (as PT is technically 8 hours behind during winter)?

Comment: Yes, it's 7 hours behind UTC ("-07:00") or 8 hours behind UTC ("-08:00")

Comment: I would expect your first assumption to be correct. Can you provoke that web service to return a date in winter and simply compare the time zones?

Comment: @Jon Skeet Happy to accept your comment as an answer if posted as one. Thank you.

Comment: @f1sh Good suggestion. It does return "2021-01-07T23:59:00-08:00". Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](https://24timezones.com/usa_time/nv_clark/las_vegas.php) in Las vegas DST ends on November 1st.
And DST stands for [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) not for "summer time".